# Intersection of subgroup and normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know the standard result that " let G be group and let H be subgroup and N be normal subgroup of G then H ∩ N is normal subgroup of H"
   but is,  H ∩ N is the normal subgroup of G? if no, then is, there is counter example? I am unable to find such examples. I had tried for S3, as {(1), (1,3)} is subgroup of S3 and A3 is normal subgroup of S3 and this gives A3 ∩ {(1),(13)} = {(1)} and this is normal subgroup of S3. so I am unable to find counter example.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not true.

In particular, it's not true that if $A$ is normal in $B$ and $B$ is normal in $G$ then $A$ is normal in $G$. For instance, look at $G = S_4$ and its subgroups $A = \langle (12)(34) \rangle$ and $B=\{(12)(34),(13)(42),(23)(41),e \}$. $A$ is normal in $B$, $B$ is normal in $S_4$, but $A$ is not normal in $G$ (And in particular, $A \cap B = A$). $\diamondsuit$

Comment: still I don't get, my question is " if H is subgroup of G and N is normal subgroup of G then H ∩ N is normal subgroup of " G. "

Comment: I think he answered to your question. Take $G=S_4$, $H=A$ and $N=B$. Then $N\unlhd G$, $H\leq G$ but $H\cap N=H$ which is nonnormal in $G$.